# как запустить react приложение после того как собрал и минимизировал все webpack'ом

Tags: reactjs, webpack

после сборки проекта появляется файл html в который подключен bandle.js со всем проектом, вопрос заключается в том как запустить этот html  чтобы все работало как в create-react- app когда пишешь npm run start

Comment: Раздать статику любым http-сервером, например nginx

Comment: а что если у меня на 3000 порту react на 5000 express сервер?

Comment: @Emilcul Запустить на другом порте?)))